# how to find the root in $x^3-x^2+6x+24$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying my hand on these types of expressions.  how to find the root in $x^3-x^2+6x+24$ ?
please write any idea you have and easy ways please ! thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method

Comment: x=-2 is a root of the cubic.

Comment: You could use   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = x^3-x^2+6x+24.$

$f(-2) = \cdots = 0$

Therefore $x + 2$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

Find the quotient by long division.

Factorize the quotient.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Rational Root Theorem](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/rtnlroot.htm), if there is a rational root for this polynomial, it must be a divisor of 24, i.e., in $\pm \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12 \}$.  Trial and error reveals that $x = -2$ is the only root from this set.  Equivalently, $x + 2$ is a factor of the polynomial.

Using [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division), you can factor the polynomial into $(x + 2)(x^2  - 3x + 12)$.  From there, it's a simple matter of applying the quadratic formula.

If you hadn't been fortunate enough to be given a cubic that happened to have a rational root, you could use a generic root-finding method like the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) or [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to find that first real root.

There is a [Cubic Formula](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/), but it's rather complex.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) you can find one rational root $a$.

Then use [Polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) to write $$x^3-x^2+6x+24$$  as $$(x-a)g(x)$$ where $g$ is a  quadratic polynomial.

Note that the other two roots of the above polynomials are the roots of $g$

Comment: can u please use it so i can see

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to try out some of the small values like -1,-2,1 and 2. That's what I do. Usually it does the trick but I don't expect it to work everytime. In your case -2 is a solution. Guessing one root is very helpful.

$$x^3-x^2+6x+24=0$$
$$\Rightarrow x^3+2x^2-3x^2-6x+12x+24=0$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2(x+2)-3x(x+2)+12(x+2)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (x+2)(x^2-3x+12)=0$$
The quadratic does not have a real root.